# Metamask transaction is expected to fail on a Smart Contract function that batches ether transfer

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

So basically I'm trying to write an application that is able to send multiple addresses specified amount of tokens or ethers, after the admin has "approved" a transaction from the dashboard.

Smart Contract Code -

```
interface ERC20Token {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}



contract SimpleContract {
    address public owner;
    ERC20Token public TetherToken;
    ERC20Token public USDCoin;

    struct Transaction {
        address payable recipient;
        uint amount;
        string coinType;
    }

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
        TetherToken = ERC20Token(0x97192842006D54AC767D004c96Dd3723194c8AcC);
        USDCoin = ERC20Token(0xFE724a829fdF12F7012365dB98730EEe33742ea2);
    }


    function batchTransaction(Transaction[] memory transactions) public payable {
        for(uint i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++) {
            if(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(transactions[i].coinType)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("ETH"))) {
                transactions[i].recipient.transfer(transactions[i].amount);
            } else if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(transactions[i].coinType)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("USDC"))) {
                USDCoin.transferFrom(msg.sender, transactions[i].recipient, transactions[i].amount);
            } else if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(transactions[i].coinType)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("USDT"))) {
                TetherToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, transactions[i].recipient, transactions[i].amount);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Front-end React Code that interacts with batch transaction -

```
    async function batchUpdate() {
        let transactionsToSend = [...transactions.filter((transaction) => {
            return checkedIndices?.find((tx) => tx.id === transaction._id)?.isChecked == true
        }).map((tx) => ({
            recipient: tx.address,
            amount: utils.parseEther(tx.amount.toString()),
            coinType: tx.coinType
        }))]

        MadRiverContract.methods.batchTransaction([...transactionsToSend]).send({ from: account }).on('receipt', (receipt) => {
            updateStatusBatch('approved', checkedIndices.filter((tx) => tx.isChecked == true).map((tx) => tx.id), receipt.transactionHash)
         }).catch((error) => {
             alert(error.message)
             console.log(error)
         })
    }
```

For interacting with the smart contract, I'm using useDapp to connect to the wallet, and web3.js only for this batchTransfer function. When I try to execute the batch transfer, this appears.

[image]

What's the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/119491/this-transaction-is-expected-to-fail-trying-to-execute-it-is-expected-to-be-exp

The problem was instead of passing `string` type, I was passing a number. So most likely you are passing wrong argument here:

```
MadRiverContract.methods.batchTransaction([...transactionsToSend])
```

`[...transactionsToSend]` argument is causing error